# Possible to have buildfarm status in PR on Github?

Tags: ros, buildfarm, jenkins, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have configured bloom to enable Pull Request testing on the buildfarm.

On the Github side, giving admin access to the whole org seems a bit too much, so I am using the alternative solution using webhook, as described [here in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm/Pull%20request%20testing).

On a PR, a build is triggered on the buildfarm, but no feedback is given on the Github PR page.

Is this behavior normal while using webhook, or am I missing a configuration somewhere?

- The [build on the buildfarm](http://build.ros.org/job/Npr__ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver__ubuntu_focal_amd64/1/).
- The [PR on Github](https://github.com/ixblue/ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver/pull/6)
- A [PR on ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/2038) with a build status at the bottom.

Edit: here are the permissions I have given: (a bit more that what is advised on the Wiki). But I have just noticed that the **Pull request review comments** is missing.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361118/possible-to-have-buildfarm-status-in-pr-on-github?/) by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2020-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution for me was to give [ros-pull-request-builder](https://github.com/ros-pull-request-builder) write access to the specific repo. Without granting access to the whole organization:
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2020-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the console output of your job I see that you're getting permission denied from github (see log snippet below). I think that you have not given enough privileges for the webook to write the PR status back to your repository.

```
01:42:02 Setting status of 5e8c461ac29ae9919d6fd9e52ab33993f7a39a57 to SUCCESS with url http://build.ros.org/job/Npr__ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver__ubuntu_focal_amd64/1/ and message: 'Build finished. '
01:42:02 Using context: Npr__ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver__ubuntu_focal_amd64
01:42:03 FileNotFoundException means that the credentials Jenkins is using is probably wrong. Or the user account does not have write access to the repo.
01:42:03 org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-status"}
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.handleApiError(Requester.java:699)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:306)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:247)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.createCommitStatus(GHRepository.java:1104)
01:42:03    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.status.GhprbSimpleStatus.createCommitStatus(GhprbSimpleStatus.java:283)
01:42:03    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.status.GhprbSimpleStatus.onBuildComplete(GhprbSimpleStatus.java:241)
01:42:03    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbBuilds.onCompleted(GhprbBuilds.java:205)
01:42:03    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbBuildListener.onCompleted(GhprbBuildListener.java:28)
01:42:03    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:209)
01:42:03    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1925)
01:42:03    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
01:42:03    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
01:42:03    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
01:42:03 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.github.com/repos/ixblue/ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver/statuses/5e8c461ac29ae9919d6fd9e52ab33993f7a39a57
01:42:03    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor63895.newInstance(Unknown Source)
01:42:03    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
01:42:03    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1950)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1945)
01:42:03    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1514)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:625)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:607)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:285)
01:42:03    ... 11 more
01:42:03 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.github.com/repos/ixblue/ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver/statuses/5e8c461ac29ae9919d6fd9e52ab33993f7a39a57
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1896)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
01:42:03    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
01:42:03    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
01:42:03    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:615)
01:42:03    ... 13 more
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2020-09-09**:
Thank you.
But even with **Pull request review comments** activated, I still have the permission error.
Do you have any idea which permission I should enable in the screenshot I have added to my answer?

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2020-09-09**:
Maybe the **Statuses** choice can grant access.

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2020-09-09**:
Sadly, [no](http://build.ros.org/job/Npr__ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver__ubuntu_focal_amd64/3/consoleFull)...

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2020-12-18**:
In order to install the webhook the admin or maintain permissions must be applied. Once the hook is installed in your repository you can revoke the permission but if the hook ever needs to update you won't receive the update.